# Question about Eloquent property "#with=[]"

Tags: eloquent

I have an app that uses the Eloquent dynamic array builder to create a collection:

```
$events=Event::with('Memory')->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

An event looks like this:

```
 #fillable: array:3 
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "events"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      ...
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      ...
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [?
        "id" => 10
        "eventTitle" => "event a512345678"
        "eventDescription" => "333guygflgg"
        "user_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2021-08-05 13:02:25"
        "updated_at" => "2021-08-05 13:02:25"
        "memory_id" => null
      ]
      ...
      
      #guarded: array:1 [?]
    }
```

In that, I see:

#with: []
#withCount: []

For event #10, there are 3 related records.

id   eventTitle        mem_id  memTitle
10   event 512345678   10 mem  2512345678
10   event 512345678   29 mem  5a
10   event 512345678   40 mem  6a

Shouldn't the event object have

#with: ['memories']
#withCount: ['3']

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hm, I see `"memory_id" => null` -> than memoryes count is 0

Comment: Have you already define relation between Memory and Event?

Comment: Yes. I have a model of both tables:
class Event extends Model
    public function memoryof()
    {  
      return $this->hasMany(Memory::class);
    }
class Memory extends Model
 public function event()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::class);
    }
TheSchema
   Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('memory_id')
  
  Schema::create('memories', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreignId('event_id')
  I get the data the Eloquent way:
   $events=Event::with('Memory')->get();  ??? do I need the ->get();